# StorageException: Could not open resulting stream

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

```
 var storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
                        storage.child(product.name).putBytes(convert.toByteArray()).addOnSuccessListener {
                            progress.dismiss()
                            startActivity(Intent(this, ProductList::class.java))
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Product Uploaded Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        progress.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Uploaded...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
```

[I am getting this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy4XV.png)

I have tried changing the project but couldn't solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the following exception:

> StorageException: Could not open resulting stream

A possible reason might be due to improper security rules. If you're in the development phase, then you can use the following rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But remember, once your app goes into production, you have to [secure your app accordingly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security).

Another possible reason might be due to trying to open large files. According to the official documentation of [StorageReference#putBytes(byte[])](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#putBytes(byte%5B%5D))

> Asynchronously uploads byte data to this StorageReference. This is not recommended for large files. Instead upload a file via putFile or an InputStream via putStream.

Comment: Hey Sanan. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?